# Do we have any inbuilt function which will tell me if this value present in the column

Tags: plsql

Do we have any inbuilt function which will tell me if this value present in the column.

I mean i want to know wether some particular value is there or not in the column
I have list of thigs to be checked like A,B,C is present in col2 at some rows number of tabl3...
So do i have some function which gives like true or false...or anything like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if one string exits within a string (e.g. a column in your table) with the INSTR function, or with the LIKE operator:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE INSTR(col2, 'A') > 0

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col2 LIKE '%A%'
```

You can then add additional predicates by using the OR operator.